# Need SPLIT ARRAY for post in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I have a question form where the administrator can choose whether the question will be objective or multiple choice, but when the user marks 2 checkboxes, I pass the ID to the API and it cannot receive an array just an integer. I need to separate the array and pass it unitarily

```
PAYLOAD

0: {survey: {id: "252"}, question: {id: "385"}, personSurvey: {id: "246"},…}
 personSurvey: {id: "246"}
 question:{id: "385"}
 questionAlternative: {id: [["367", "369"]]}
 survey: {id: "252"}`
```

My HandleSubmit

```
function handleSubmit(data: any) {
    setLoading(true);
    apiBase.create("answer/all", data.answer);

    survey &&
      apiBase
        .find<IEventDetailDTO>(
          "event-detail",
          `typeDetail=ID&eventEventTypeId=3&idReference=${survey.id}`,
        )
        .then(
          ({ data: eventDetails }) =>
            eventDetails[0] &&
            apiBase.patch(
              "event-detail",
              eventDetails[0],
              { dateSurveyAnswered: nowDate() },
              { headers: { noMessage: true } },
            ),
        );

    apiBase
      .patch(
        "/person-survey",
        { id: personSurveyId },
        { statusTarget: "RESPONDIDO" },
        { headers: { noMessage: true } },
      )
      .then(() => setLoading(false));
  }
```

FORM Component

```
  const getValue = (choiceRef) => {
    const values = choiceRef.filter((i) => i.checked).map((i) => i.value);
    return [values];
  };
```

I need the questionAlternative ID to be passed separately and that it not lose the question id reference